# Recursive Query for Date Range

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to create a query so that I can generate a date range between a specific start and end point.

I have the following:

```
WITH DATE_RANGE(DATE_FOR_SHIFT)
     AS (SELECT DATE('2015-04-01')
         FROM   SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE_FOR_SHIFT + 1 DAY
         FROM   DATE_RANGE
         WHERE  DATE_FOR_SHIFT <= @END)
SELECT DATE_FOR_SHIFT
FROM   DATE_RANGE;
```

Output (assuming that `@END` equals `2015-05-01`):

```
2015-04-01
2015-04-02
2015-04-03
2015-04-04
...
2015-05-01
```

The output is correct, but I want to be able to change the start and points based on parameters provided rather than having to rewrite the query or have a SQL injection prone query.

How would I rewrite this query in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Side note: Date/time/timestamp types, like all positive, contiguous-range types (everything but an explicit integer count), should be queried with an exclusive upper-bound.  [This blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) deals with SQL Server, but the problem is actually due to how numbers are represented in general (it's not actually a tech issue).  Oh, and in DB2 you can specify the number of fractional seconds for a timestamp, so it'd apply anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of playing with this in perl gives me:

```
#!/opt/myperl/5.20.2/bin/perl

use 5.10.0;
use DBI;
use DBD::DB2;
use Data::Dump;

my $sql = <<EOSQL;

WITH DATE_RANGE(DATE_FOR_SHIFT)
     AS (SELECT CAST(? AS DATE)
         FROM   SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE_FOR_SHIFT + 1 DAY
         FROM   DATE_RANGE
         WHERE  DATE_FOR_SHIFT < CAST(? AS DATE))
SELECT DATE_FOR_SHIFT
FROM   DATE_RANGE;

EOSQL


my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:DB2:sample');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached($sql);
$sth->execute('2015-04-01','2015-05-01');
my $rc = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
dd($rc);
```

This does give an error during prepare ("The recursive common table expression "MYSCHEMA.DATE_RANGE" may contain an infinite loop") that I haven't figured out yet, but the fetch does work, the final return goes from 04-01 to 05-01.  Hopefully you can port this to your desired language.

Comment: The `SELECT CAST(? AS DATE)` line was effectively what I was wanting, although I poorly asked it. Applying this to my original query was exactly what I was wanting.

Comment: You'd only need the cast if the parms aren't dates to begin with.  If `@End` by itself worked in your original, then `@Str` would also work by itself as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your SELECT is fine, other than the hard coded start date.

What I think you're missing is wrapping it in either a stored procedure or user defined table function (UDTF).  Assuming you'll want to JOIN the date range to other tables, I'd suggest a UDTF.

```
create function date_range (@str date, @end date) 
returns table (date_for_shift date) 
language SQL
reads SQL data
return
   WITH DATE_RANGE(DATE_FOR_SHIFT)
     AS (SELECT @str
         FROM   SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE_FOR_SHIFT + 1 DAY
         FROM   DATE_RANGE
         WHERE  DATE_FOR_SHIFT <= @END)
    SELECT DATE_FOR_SHIFT
    FROM   DATE_RANGE;
```

Then you'd call it...

```
select * from table(date_range(date('2015-04-01'),date('2015-05-01'))) as tbl;
```

However, instead of generating this date range on the fly....consider simply creating a calender (aka dates) table.  Basically just a table with dates from say 1900-01-01 to 2500-12-31..or whatever you'd like.  Beside the date column,  you can include lots of additional columns such as business_day, holiday, ect.. that make life much easier.

Google "SQL calendar table" for plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Generating a table for dates isn't an option in my situation.

Comment: Why not?  If the answer is similar to "I'm a developer, the DBAs won't let me create tables" then ask if one already exists.  If not, ask them to create one.

Comment: @Cameron - Seconding Calendar table.  They are, hands down, the most useful dimension/analysis table you can make.  When properly indexed (and since they don't get updated, you can have about as many as you want), you can get index-based range queries to ask just about any sort of temporal question you can think of - stuff you'd normally need function calls for.